# function trapped in comment h3 reply title

Tags: comments-template

I have this piece of code that enables the post author to block individual users that have commented on the author's post. It works well except when the comment reply link is clicked... see the code and the image below to see what happens. It looks like the checkbox is trapped in a `h3` tag?

```
function block_user_in_comments_form($return){
    global $comment, $post, $current_user;
    
    if ($post->post_author == $comment->user_id) {return  $return;} // don't do for post author
    $comment_user = new WP_User( $comment->user_id );
    if (in_array('administrator', $comment_user->roles)) {return  $return;} // don't do for admin...
    $block_users = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'block-user-comments', true );
    
    
    if ( current_user_can('moderate_comments') || ($current_user->ID == $post->post_author)) { // you might need changing this line
        $checked = ' ';
        
        if (is_array($block_users) && !empty($block_users) && in_array($comment->user_id, $block_users)) {
            $checked = ' checked="checked" ';
        }
        
        $form = '<form method="POST" action="'.get_the_permalink($post->ID).'">';
        $form .= 'Block user? <input type="checkbox" name="block-user-comments" class="blk_user_comments" '.$checked.' value="yes" />';
        $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$comment->user_id.'" />';
        $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="the_post" value="'.$post->ID.'" />';
        $form .= wp_nonce_field( 'block-user-comments', '_wpnonce', true, false );
        $form .= ' <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="submit_blk_user_comments" /></form>';
        ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(function($){
                    $('.submit_blk_user_comments').hide();
                    $('.blk_user_comments').change(function(){
                        $(this).siblings('.submit_blk_user_comments').show();
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php
        $return .= $form;
    } elseif (is_array($block_users) && !empty($block_users) && in_array($comment->user_id, $block_users)) {
        $return .= '<p>"You can not leave a comment on this post" </p>';
    }
    return $return;
}
add_filter('get_comment_author', 'block_user_in_comments_form');
function block_user_in_comments(){
    if ( isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'block-user-comments' ) ) {
        if (isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['the_post'])) {
            $user_id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_id']);
            $post_id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['the_post']);
            
            $comment_user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            if (in_array('administrator', $comment_user->roles)) {return;} // don't do for admin...
            $post = get_post($post_id);
            if ($post->post_author == $user_id) {return;} // don't do for post author
            
            $block_users = get_post_meta($post_id, 'block-user-comments', true );
            if ($_POST['block-user-comments'] === 'yes') {
                if (is_array($block_users) && !empty($block_users)) {
                    $block_users[] = $user_id;
                } else {
                    $block_users = array($user_id);
                }
            } elseif (is_array($block_users) && !empty($block_users)) {
                $key = array_search($user_id, $block_users);
                if ($key != NULL || $key !== FALSE)
                    unset($block_users[$key]);
            }
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'block-user-comments', $block_users );
        }
    } 
}
add_filter('template_redirect', 'block_user_in_comments');
function my_comments_open( $open, $post_id ) {
    global $current_user;
    
    $block_users = get_post_meta($post_id, 'block-user-comments', true );
    if (is_array($block_users) && !empty($block_users)) {
        $key = array_search($current_user->ID, $block_users);
        if ($key != NULL || $key !== FALSE) {
            $open = false;
        }
    }
    return $open;
}
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'my_comments_open', 1, 2 );
```

[image: Screenshot]